# C++ Loop: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token

Tags: c++

I have a loop like below, I think the problem is with the inner for loops marked "See here". Whats the problem with that?

```
// measure time to write different sizes of data
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(int); i++) {
    lengthMod = sizes[i]/sizeof(int) - 1;

    start = wall_clock_time();

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 10; j++) // << See here!!!
        tmp = 1;

    // force any write back cache to flush. read from other data source
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < REPS; j++) // << Or here!!!
        tmp = j;

    end = wall_clock_time();
    timeTaken = ((float)(end - start))/1000000000;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d, %1.2f \n", sizes[i]/1024, ((float)(end - start))/1000000000);
}
```

You can see the **[full source on GitHub](https://github.com/jiewmeng/cs3210-assign1/blob/master/cache-write.cpp)** ~line 32

---

```
g++ -O3 cache-write.cpp -o cache-write -lrt
cache-write.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cache-write.cpp:36:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
cache-write.cpp:36:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
cache-write.cpp:36:29: error: name lookup of ‘j’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping [-fpermissive]
cache-write.cpp:36:29: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
cache-write.cpp:36:32: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
cache-write.cpp:44:11: error: ‘data1’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [cache-write] Error 1
```

Comment: Remove the trailing `;` from your `#define REPS` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using #define where you declare REPS, use

```
const unsigned int REPS = whatever;
```

Generally in C++ avoid using #define because it can easily cause the kind of problem you're having.

Comment: Is there any situation where I should use `#define` instead? And is there any difference between the 2?

Comment: @JiewMeng: `#define SYMBOL value` is a preprocessor command. Basically the preprocessor will run over your code and replace any occurrence of the defined `SYMBOL` with the given value (at least in most cases, although some more complicated things are possible). The bad thing about this is that you can't watch a value in a debugger, so you can't set a breakpoint whenever your SYMBOL gets accessed for example, because the `SYMBOL` doesn't exist in your program anymore, it has been replaced. The `const unsigned v = value;` on the other hand is going to be processed by the compiler.

Comment: #define is dealt with by the pre-processor. The pre-processor does things like get all the text from #include files and put it into one long code string. #define as you used it just means directly replace the word "REPS" in my code with "128 * MB;". The pre-processor simply manipulates the text of your source code before compilation starts. You can often pass a flag to the compiler which will cause it to dump the code out to a file before it starts compiling it so you can see what the preprocessor did.

Comment: const unsigned int is proper C++ code that the compiler understands and which it can generate proper error messages for.

Comment: Ah, yes Zeta makes a good point about debug-ability. Also, the pre-processor doesn't understand what C++ namespaces are. So it's possible you could write code, then #include somebody else's code which has #defines in it that actually then causes unexpected changes to the text of your code. When that happens, the source of the problem can be hard to track down.

Comment: The only time I can think you'd want to use #define is if you want to use the predefined macros __LINE__ or __FILE__ to automatically generate a log statement that includes information about the filename and line that the log statement originated from. (Line and File are supposed to have double underscores either side of them, but stackoverflow treated that as meaning bold)

Answer (score 3):

You have a semi colon at the end of the definition of REPS:

```
#define REPS 128 * MB;
```